# Can't run psql from an ant target running in NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: postgresql, netbeans, ant, psql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2 on Windows 7. I'm trying to run an Ant target using an apply tag with the executable property set to psql from a NetBeans 8.0.2 build file. I have created a pgpass.conf file in the right place with the correct password for the postgres user and I can run psql at a command prompt without having to enter a password. But when I run the Ant target, I get an error message in the output file saying the target failed because no password was supplied. What am I doing wrong? The target looks like this:

```
<filelist id="create-dbfiles" dir="${root}" files="createdb.sql"/> 
    <target name="create-db">
        <apply executable="psql"  addsourcefile="false" output="output.txt">
            <arg value="-U postgres" />
            <arg value="-w" />
            <filelist refid="create-dbfiles"/>
            <redirector>
                <inputmapper type="glob" from="*" to="${root}\*" />           
            </redirector>
        </apply>
    </target>
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I already said in my post that I have created a pgpass file which is working correctly when I run psql from a command prompt. The specific problem is that it won't run from the Ant environment.

Comment: I have two accounts on Windows 7 Home Edition: my normal account (call it David) which is a Standard User and then Admin with full admin privileges. I have a pgpass.conf file for both in their respective postgresql directories. I can run psql from the command prompt logged on as David or Admin without being prompted for a password. I can also open PgAdmin without a passsword in both accounts. I run Netbeans as Admin.

Comment: If I remove the `-w` parameter, the ant build hangs (I left it for 90 minutes once). If I include it, I get an immediate error message in the output file. I haven't tried `exec`. I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: I get the same error with an exec tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name got me thinking about the exec tag but trying to run `psql` directly via an `exec` tag or an `apply` tag still threw up errors about a password not being supplied. Then I realised that `psql` ran smoothly from the cmd prompt. I started playing around with calling `cmd.exe` and passing a command to the command line, and found a solution:

```
<filelist id="clean-dbfiles" dir="${root}" files="cleandb.sql"/> 
<target name="clean-db">
    <apply executable="cmd.exe"  addsourcefile="true" >
        <filelist refid="clean-dbfiles"/>
        <env key="PGPASSWORD" value="rootpassword"></env>
        <arg value="/c"></arg>
        <arg value="psql -w -U postgres -f " />
        <srcfile />
    </apply>
</target>
<filelist id="create-dbfiles" dir="${root}"  files="createdb.sql"/> 
<target name="create-db">
    <apply executable="cmd.exe"  addsourcefile="true" >
        <filelist refid="create-dbfiles"/>                    
        <env key="PGPASSWORD" value="rootpassword"></env>
        <arg value="/c"></arg>
        <arg value="psql -w -U postgres -f "/>
        <srcfile />
    </apply>
</target>
```

Here are the two key targets for creating a build script for a postgres database. Note the following points:

1. Run `cmd.exe` not `psql` directly
2. Set `addsourcefile` to `true` because I want to call neat little self-contained SQL files for each target.
3. Use `apply` with a `filelist` because for my `createtables` or `populate` targets I may have a directory of separate SQL files
4. Give up on hoping to invoke the pgpass.conf file. For some reason Ant in NetBeans can't access it. Resort to the PGPASSWORD environment key and set it to  the desired password. This is running locally for development purposes so security isn't an issue.
5. You need to pass the /c switch to cmd.exe so that you can then pass a command line. I didn't separate the psql command line into separate arguments because I think the complete line is being passed to cmd.exe as a single argument.
6. addsourcefile is set to true so each file in the filelist is appended to the psql command line just after the -f switch and everything works a treat.

Voilà! What a fuss! I had no similar difficulty with MySql because you can pass the password to the command line directly.

Comment: Good find! For testing/dev stuff I too find the high security strategy in Postgres sometimes a bit of a hindrance. What adds to this is the fact that Postgres' main target platform is Linux, not Windows. And I think it's a bit easier there because you could put the definition of `PGPASSWORD` and the call to `psql` on a single command line if I'm not mistaken. The fact that `psql` when invoked from Java doesn't find the `pgpass.conf` file seems weird though. You might want to post this to the Postgres mailing list

Comment: Another option might be to create a batch file that defines the various `PGPASSWORD` (and maybe others) before calling `psql`. Then call the batch file from Ant